# how to send HTTP request to submit form in node.js to another website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I want to submit a form of another sites & want get response. But cant understand how to do this. Can anyone please help me ?

My target site : http://xyz.php

My code :

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'xyz.com',
  path: '/xyz.php?textSearch=234567'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module:

```
var request = require('request')
request.post('http://nbr.gov.bd/getbinfield.php', {
  form: {
    txtSearch: '...search for something',
    bthSubmit: 'Search'
  }
}, function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(body)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use POST request, because form tag contain **method** attribute

```
 <form id="frmThis" name="frmThis" method="post" action="">
```

Try this code:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var post_data = querystring.stringify({
    txtSearch: "17051017387"
})

var options = {
    host: 'nbr.gov.bd',
    path: '/getbinfield.php',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }
};

callback = function(response) {
    console.log(arguments);
    var str = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log(str);
    });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback)
req.write(post_data)
req.end()
```